# How to check for decimal number

Tags: yup

I have a schema:

```js
const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  decimal: Yup.number().integer('invalid decimal'),
});
```

I need to check if the number is a decimal, but I found only `Integer` in docs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add a custom validation test e.g. with regex.

```
const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  decimal: Yup.number().test(
    'is-decimal',
    'invalid decimal',
    value => (value + "").match(/^\d*\.{1}\d*$/),
  ),
});
```

Comment: Yes I know, I just want to know maybe there is some built in method to do this

Comment: Don't think there is a built in method to do it

Comment: This won't work in international scenari where thousands and decimal separator can be `.` or `,`

Answer (score 1):

```
const digitsOnly = (value: string) => /^\d*[\.{1}\d*]\d*$/.test(value) || value.length === 0



const schema = yup.object().shape({
    inputEntry: yup
            .string()
            .test('inputEntry', 'The field should have digits only', digitsOnly)
});
```

Above code is used for allowing only decimal,whole and null values in the input field.

Comment: digitsOnly has an extra escape character.
please edit to 

const digitsOnly = (value:string) => /^\d*[.{1}\d*]\d*$/.test(value) || value.length === 0

Answer (score -2):

just keep yup.number for decimals